# Error installing h5pyViewer by pip install h5pyViewer

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, h5py

I am trying to install h5pyViewer using `pip install h5pyViewer` but it is giving an error.
`Collecting h5pyViewer Using cached h5pyViewer-0.0.1.6.tar.gz (74 kB) ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /home/madhur/miniconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kx4npfnx/h5pyviewer/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kx4npfnx/h5pyviewer/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9tb86g5b cwd: /tmp/pip-install-kx4npfnx/h5pyviewer/ Complete output (6 lines): Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "/tmp/pip-install-kx4npfnx/h5pyviewer/setup.py", line 82 print ':'+ver+':'+gitcmt+':' ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(':'+ver+':'+gitcmt+':')? ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Python version is 3.8.2
pip version is 20.2.4
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[h5pyViewer 0.0.1.6](https://pypi.org/project/h5pyViewer/0.0.1.6/) was released to PyPI at Nov 5, 2015. The code is obviously Python2-only. The problem was fixed in the git repository in commit [5229b39](https://github.com/ganymede42/h5pyViewer/commit/5229b39f726183908bdbc7fe5fcfdf792696b5c4) at Nov 12, 2018.

Unfortunately it's still not compatible with Python3 due to [octal `0755`](https://github.com/ganymede42/h5pyViewer/blob/065bd2361df31fd38fa2eec087c91d1c2c06b1ab/setup.py#L98) and [other compatibility problems](https://github.com/ganymede42/h5pyViewer/issues/3#issuecomment-566522786). The bottom line: it's still Python2-only.

There is a [fork](https://github.com/Eothred/h5pyViewer) updated for Python 3. You can try it:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Eothred/h5pyViewer.git
```